# Can homosexuality be discussed philosophically?

Tags: reference-request

My friend tells me it depends on how you view homosexuality. He says if you see it as a belief/religion, then yes. Otherwise no. What do you think?

Comment: Do you mean if "you see [homosexuality] as belief/religion"? That is, if you view homosexuality as *a* belief/religion? And in any case, I'd say you can discuss pretty much anything philosophically if you try.

Comment: Considering it as a belief/religion is the opinion my friend suggested to determine whether it can be discussed philosophically. I put it on to use as an example. My main question is if and how the practice of homosexuality can be discussed philosophically, like what questions it can pose etc.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by seeing homosexuality as a religion? This seems quite nonsensical to me.

Comment: You can discuss anything philosophically.

Comment: Whatever your ultimate concern is, that is your religion; that is the true definition of religion. Homosexuality is a lifestyle that has an affect on many aspects of a person's life. People who advocate it actively sets it as their ultimate concern.

Comment: Any topic abstractly constructed is susceptible to be studied philosophically. Just construct an abstract, deep and logically argumented problem and you can make philosophy (I think even on belief/religion).

Comment: How is homosexuality a lifestyle? I think of a lifestyle as something you can _choose_. Whether you can choose to be gay or not is highly debatable. Also, if you mean your personal,  "true" definition of religion, instead of a classical one, don't forget to mention it in the question's body

Comment: Point taken. I will now gear this back to my original question before going any further off topic.

Comment: @Ava Is heterosexuality a religion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discuss philosophically the nature of sexuality, and homosexuality in particular. Also, I don't see at all how homosexuality is a belief or a religion (or both). We can be utterly straightforward and look up what the word means in the dictionary: Merriam-Webster defines 'homosexuality' as 'the quality or state of being homosexual'. Can a quality be a belief or a religion? I don't think so. However, 'homosexuality is not unnatural', for example,  is a perfectly legitimate belief (I can't think of a homosexuality-based religion, sorry :) ).

**EDIT:** take a look at [this](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/homosexuality/) SEP article on the subject, it also contains a huge list of references to works of actual philosophers.

Comment: You say that we can but give nothing to support that claim. Example maybe?

Comment: Are you happy now? :)

Comment: Thank you for the reference (and the edit to my question)!

Comment: Well, does my answer answer your question?  :)

Comment: Partially, if you could just give an example to support your claim. Even though my question was 'can it be' and not 'how can it be' you must add the 'how' for any answer to be accepted. Just how can homosexuality be discussed philosophically?

Comment: The reference you suggested did answer my question so for that I will accept. When ever a question is asked, an answer is expected to give a reason why or 'how' the answer is correct and I  didn't accept your answer earlier because you didn't explain 'how' your answer was correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14142/discussion-between-ava-and-user132181)

Answer (score 1):

You can...but that depends on what *about* homosexuality you are discussing.

Are you discussing whether it is morally 'right' or 'wrong' to be a homosexual?

Are you discussing the idea of homosexuality as a philosophy in and of itself?

Are you discussing the very concept of whether or not homosexuality has any philosophical bearing at all?

Homosexuality is a broad concept, and has plenty of areas of conflict that can be discussed from a philosophical standpoint.  Its very nature, its impact on society, whether or not it is a choice, what that would mean for society and individuals, all are ripe concepts for discussion.

Homosexuality itself is a very, very broad topic, and 'discussing it philosophically' would be akin to discussing a religion, an ethnicity, a moral viewpoint, or any idea - you can do it, but without context or a direction to discuss it in, there isn't much point.

Comment: By moralistically, do you mean morally? Discussing things moralistically is not generally in the provence of philosophy.

Comment: @virmaior Yes, I believe I do. My apologies for the incorrect terminology.